Counting polygons inside raster cells in R
I am trying to do something i thought was easy, which is to calculate the number of polygons in each raster cell. I am trying both solutions here: R: How can I count how many points are in each cell of my grid? but none of them works and I am getting crazy with all the different packages used. I would like a terra solution but not sure how to achieve this, and at this point I'm open to any package.
Here are some dummy data and my code so far:
# Load packages
pacman::p_load(terra, raster, rnaturalearth, rts, sf)

# Load dummy polygons
cntrs <- ne_countries(country = c("united kingdom", "argentina", "singapore"), type = "countries")

# Reproject
cntrs <- project(vect(cntrs), "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0")

# Create empty raster grid
r <- terra::rast(xmin = -180, xmax = 180, ymin = -90, ymax = 90,
          res = 10,
          crs = "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

r[] <- 0

### First solution of the link: rasterize
terra::rasterize(cntrs, r, fun = "count")

# gets a warning message and an empty raster
Warning message:
  Failed to compute min/max, no valid pixels found in sampling. (GDAL error 1) 

I have no idea why the raster is empty. In the examples in the link, they also have some points not overlapping any raster cell.
### Second solution: cellFromXY
# change polygons format
cntrs <- as(st_geometry(st_as_sf(cntrs)), "Spatial")
table(cellFromXY(r, cntrs))

# Gets error message:
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
            unable to find an inherited method for function ‘cellFromXY’ for signature ‘"SpatRaster", "SpatialPolygons"’

Even if my rts version is rts_1.1-14, same as on the manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rts/rts.pdf), where they write that the "object" can be a SpatRaster...
# Tried converting SpatRaster to RasterLayer as in the examples linked
r <- raster::raster(r)
table(cellFromXY(r, cntrs))

# Gets error message:
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=S4; target=double].

In the example they are using SpatialPoints but I have polygons so I'm trying with SpatialPolygons, which doesn't seem to work either. Any insight is appreciated.
EDIT: creating the empty raster with appropriate limits and resolution for the chosen projection (Mollweide is in metres) solves the problem.

r <- rast(xmin = -18000000, xmax = 18000000, ymin = -9000000, ymax =
9000000, res = 10000, crs = "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
+datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")


Something is a bit strange with how you create your empty raster. Projection is set to molweide so xmin,max,ymin, ymax are meters but you set them as -180,180,-90,90 which looks more degrees to me. Print the extent of cntrs and compare with that of r

Thanks for spotting this, I didn't think I was in Mollweide and I had to adjust this. Also the resolution is wrong, as the unit is meters. I am trying now with r <- rast(xmin = -18000000, xmax = 18000000, ymin = -9000000, ymax = 9000000, res = 10000, crs = "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"), let's see if it works.

Edit above to reflect these changes noted in comments.

Here is a way to make your code work. That is, define the raster with matching coordinates and crs and then tranform it.
library(rnaturalearth)
library(terra)
cntrs <- ne_countries(country = c("united kingdom", "argentina", "singapore"), type = "countries")

mollw <- "+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0"
cntrs <- project(vect(cntrs), mollw)

r <- terra::rast(xmin = -180, xmax = 180, ymin = -90, ymax = 90, res = 10, crs = "+proj=longlat")
r <- project(r, mollw)

x <- terra::rasterize(cntrs, r)

rasterize works well for counting points. But since you are dealing with polygons, I think what you are after is rasterGeom. For example:
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(f)
r <- rast(v, res=.05)
x <- rasterizeGeom(v, r, "count")

An alternative approximate approach is to use rasterize at a higher resolution and then aggregate:
rr <- rast(v, res=.01)
rr <- rasterize(v, rr, 1:nrow(v))
a <- aggregate(rr, 5, \(i) length(unique(i)))



Thank you, this looks more appropriate but apparently unable to run on my real data. I'm trying with a very small sample of this dataset (first 1000 rows of the 1st set of WDPA, https://www.protectedplanet.net/en/thematic-areas/wdpa?tab=WDPA) using a wide 100x100km raster grid, but the R session gets always aborted. I tried also to increase to terraOptions(memfrac = 0.8). I'm running terra_1.7-83 on R version 4.3.3 on a Windows 10 machine with 32GB RAM...

It may be because of bad polygons in the wdpa. You can check for validity.

Yes, that was part of the problem. Now all geometries are valid but I think it's still too large to manage. On the subset of 1000 rows on my computer, I get a Error: std::bad_alloc. On the full dataset, with a resolution of 1x1km, on a server (running R version 4.2.3 and terra version 1.7-78, on a Fedora 37, 380GB RAM) I get an Error: [rasterizeGeom] cannot write file. While if I try with coarser resolutions (50x50km, or 100x100km) it works.

Then you probably need to force terra to use less memory, as it tries to create a vector that is too large. You can reduce memory use with terraOptions.

It takes a long time (12 hours on 1/4 of the data) but it works and it seem to be more accurate and useful for my data. I have now found a faster solution with gdal_rasterize. But thanks a lot!
